# How to change asset publisher default not found message?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I have a `asset-publisher` of news/articles, but when I enter the name of a non-existent article in the friendly URL it appear wrong message.

Friendly URL:

```
/-/asset_publisher/instanceID/content/name-of-non-existent-article
```

Error message:

> El usuario no existe.

Translated:

> The user could not be found.

Literally translated:

> The user does not exist.

But as i said my `asset-publisher` is of articles/news and not of users.

Is there a way to change this message?

Or maybe i need to specify the content type? How?

---

I wont to hook that property:

```
the-user-could-not-be-found=The user could not be found.
```

That was not the key to hook (i was looking another version properties), look at answer.

Comment: I just tried it on a Liferay 6.2 EE with an hotfix close to the latest SP and however I configure my asset publisher it tells me "Content cannot be found" (rough translation). Could you add more detail on your Liferay version and asset publisher config?

Comment: @JonatanCloutier updated question with full version and the "real" literal, i miss it on searching the literal (i got the message on spanish and search the same literal on english, but there was multiple with the same literal.) . I dont know how to add details from asset publisher config here, there are many tabs... You need to know something specific?

Comment: It would be the content selection tab for the asset publisher and also the display template in the second tab.
For the version, as you are on EE, do you know which SP you are using?

Comment: @JonatanCloutier Updated question. I dont know what Service Pack is using and its looks like you cant seem to know for sure  [View Liferay Service Pack version](https://liferay.dev/forums/-/message_boards/view_message/35774672). Btw thanks for your time

Comment: I started with the idea of "dont hook that property" cause i think it was another proprety key and was asset-publisher fault. But now i think its more of translation mistake. Updated again with explanation. So maybe i hook it anyways if no better suggestions appears.

Comment: Well if it's really a Spanish translation mistake, hook is the only way to go (or ask support to fix on their side, but not sure if they will do it on a 6.2)

Comment: As for the sp version, you have to use the pachingtool info command on the server, it will list what is installed.

Comment: @JonatanCloutier Yeah, already use a hook, Do a answer if u want, i realized it was a translation mistake from your "Content cannot be found" and search again the literal finding it here [Language_es.properties](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/master/modules/apps/asset/asset-publisher-web/src/main/resources/content/Language_es.properties) Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I realized it was a translation mistake from `Liferay` thanks to [Jonatan Cloutier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/314198/jonatan-cloutier) comment  of `Content cannot be found`.

Finally search this literal here [Language_es.properties](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/master/modules/apps/asset/asset-publisher-web/src/main/resources/content/Language_es.properties#L76)

```
the-asset-could-not-be-found=El usuario no existe. //The user does not exist.
```

And the same literal on english [Language.properties](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/master/modules/apps/asset/asset-publisher-web/src/main/resources/content/Language.properties#L76):

```
the-asset-could-not-be-found=The asset could not be found.
```

So i decide to hook it cause it was a translation mistake only in Spanish properties.